# AG-Grid Distinguish Row Selections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I had a question regarding AG-grid that I'm not sure about.

For example, if I have the following grid.

[image]

Where each row has 2 distinctive checkboxes (master record and child record), is there a way to distinguish between when I select the master record as opposed to the child record on that row?

Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Consuming the **onCellClicked** event will provide you with the necessary column info. You will probably want to exclude grouped columns - see the example below.

```
gridOptions.onCellClicked = function(params) {
   // indicates whether the selected node is a grouped node
   if (params.node.group) {
      return;
   }
   // logs the selected column
   console.log(params.column.colId);
}
```